# Simple jQuery code does not work in VS 2010

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code in VS 2010:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
                $("p").hide('1000');
            });
        });        
</script>
</head>
<body style="width: 1007px; margin-left: 144px"> 
    <button value="button" style="width: 86px; height: 29px;">Click me !</button>
    <p style="background-color: #77003C; height: 55px;"/>    
</body>
</html>
```

But it does not work at any browser, and if I replace the jQuery file with CDN I get MicrosoftJScript error:
 `object doesn't support this property or method`
What is the problem here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p").hide('1000');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<button value="button" style="width: 86px; height: 29px;">Click me !</button>
<p style="background-color: #77003C; height: 55px;" />
```

Comment: I editted your answer, please click "Run code snippet" and tell me if it works (Editted to switch to jQuery 1.x since the browser in question is IE 8.x).

Comment: Yeah it works here, but not on my Chrome browser? is there any possibility of  problem in the browser? it is updated

Comment: Do you have javascript disabled in chrome?

Comment: I don't know , how to check that?

Comment: Add `<script>alert('not disabled');</script>` to the page. Or `<noscript>Yes, I am disabled!</noscript>`

Comment: [guide here](http://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-enable-or-disable-javascript)

Comment: It is enabled..

Comment: And you are using Chrome 54? (You can find this out under Help/About) It should say something like `Version 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit)`

Comment: yeah its version is 54.0.2840.99

Comment: Then disable every extension you have installed in Chrome, and try again. (You don't have to uninstall them, just disable for now).

Comment: still not working after disabling the extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe that.. I just modified

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

to:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">**</script>**
```

then it works fine!.Is that a bug in VS 2010??